# Notifying when a particular method is executed

Tags: java, notifications

Is there any way in Java where we are alerted when a method of a particular class is invoked. Can I register somewhere so that I can be notified when that particular method gets invoked.
For example, we want certain activities that needs to be performed when a method is invoked. Since the method is already available, we don't want to touch the existing logic, rather we just need to add a hook to that method and do some other tasks when that method is called.

Please let me know if the question is vague.

Comment: Using `Observable` and `Observer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can using `Observer Pattern`.

> An observable object can have one or more observers. An observer may
>   be any object that implements interface Observer. After an observable
>   instance changes, an application calling the Observable's
>   notifyObservers method causes all of its observers to be notified of
>   the change by a call to their update method.

So once observable object's method get invoked you can notify all observers.

```
setChanged();
notifyObservers(message);
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be a use case for AOP (http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/):
 - you can define what to do before, after or around a method execution

Answer (score 1):

One option is by configuring AOP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming

You can setup AOP to do things before, after, around method executions.